# Trying to send Bitcoins from testnet to my regtest node

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, testnet, regtest

1. I send `bitcoin regtest server` BTC to other bitcoin address of same server. I sent 5 BTC but it shows 50 BTC of that account's associated address. It received 5 BTC.

   What's the problem with this account or address?
2. I used https://tpfaucet.appspot.com/ to get free BTC for regtest server address. I send BTC to many of my addresses but I didn't receive any amount on account associated addresses.

   What's the problem on this server or regtest bitcoin?

Answer (score 3):

The `regtest` system is completely isolated from `testnet` and only exists on your local machine by default, you won't see the transaction from TPs faucet because it isn't on the same network. Blocks in your `regtest` setup can be instantly created using `bitcoin-cli setgenerate true <number of blocks>` each of which will bring into existence 50 BTC in your local wallet for testing with.

Comment: what is the port for testnet server?? how to i confirm the regtest server transaction ???

Comment: Regtest is [18444](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/86cfd23f68367af072500b1758a4c446cdd36e74/src/chainparams.cpp#L225), testnet is [18333](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/86cfd23f68367af072500b1758a4c446cdd36e74/src/chainparams.cpp#L164)

Comment: `http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/39073/how-to-use-bitcoind-jsonrpc-for-regtest-or-testnet-server-in-php` please see link answer. here write 
 
Regtest is 18332

Comment: That would be the RPC port shared by regtest and testnet, yes.

Comment: how to i confirm the regtest server transaction ???

Comment: @ShahadatHossain: confirmation works by mining a block. In regtest you can min a block with `bitcoin-cli --regtest generate 1`

Comment: I need to confirm my transaction not to generate block. I already run this and get 50btc. but i could not confirm transaction send or received. please if any idea comment here

Comment: @ShahadatHossain You don't generate blocks with testnet, miners do, just like the Mainnet. I now see your problem with receiving TP Faucet testnet coins, check your question for my answer\.